# How create dog paw in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-design

I am new in flutter. I am trying to create dog paw design in flutter and in that dog paw I want to show different images. So, Kindly help me. How I can create dog paw and show images in that paw design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hmm well i dunno if im help it or not but i suggested if you want to create dog paw by your own, you can use clip path but it will be have lot edges and hard

source : https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ClipPath-class.html
video : https://youtu.be/oAUebVIb-7s

and if you want to create an image on top of your dog paw, i think you can use stack or semantics function.